# Declaring two min-height properties

Tags: css

I am working on a site where certain sections have 100% height. To achieve this I am using the new css3 unit [vh](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) as a `min-height` (100vh).

In each section there is also a element which is absolute positioned and aligned with the bottom of the page. You can see an example of it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nwHB4/).

The problem which occurs is that on a smaller screen the button shows up upon the text.
I know that I could e.g. let the button disappear on smaller screens with `@media`; instead I would like to know if there is a css3 possibility in doing something like this:

```
.element {
  min-height: 100vh && 200px;
}
```

Any other css tricks too achieve this are also appreciated (I can change the markup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it makes no sense to use like that. You must use media query.

If it was to be added like you mentioned it would just sense if vh is undefined px would take.

But to say, it would never be applied like so.

Comment: I thought so, I was just hoping for an alternative approach. Anyway thanks for your answer!